# Converting curl command to Python request

Tags: python, python-requests

The curl command that I have that works properly is -

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic <base64userpass>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://<host>/bamboo/rest/api/latest/result/<plankey>.json?expand=results.result&os_authType=basic"
```

In Python, this is what I currently have -

```
   headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic <base64userpass>', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
   datapoints = {'expand': 'results.result', 'os_authType': 'basic'}
   url = "http://<host>/bamboo/rest/api/latest/result/<plankey>.json"
   r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=datapoints)
```

The response I get when using the Python request is `<Response [403]>`, but when using curl I get back the expected data.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: you need `params=` instead of `data=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `auth` option of requests to do basic authentication.
There are more headers that the CURL command-line handle for you (and requests will not handle them unless you use the `auth`):

```
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

Or just use:

```
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

(Change the URL and everything).

Also note that `requests` should get the `params=` (and not `data=`).

Comment: The only concern that I have with this is that the only value that I currently have is that base64 encoded value (lets say it is CmUnMm9dOkJGhaUIwBaMlNTYyJh=), and not the user/pass, would it be possible to use this method still?

Comment: Are you sure this is the value?

Comment: I just made up a series of numbers in that example, but yes I am sure that the series of numbers I am actually using is the username / password.  It has worked for other scripts in the system.  I suppose I could just decode it, but I was hoping that it would work without me having to have a password in plaintext inside of the script.

Comment: basically this string is just `base64_encode(username:password)` so what you can do is `base64_decode` on that string to get the username and password.

Comment: This answers also work for my case which is convert HTTPie command to Python Requests, thanks Man :)